# Models for Financial Economics: Determining The Amount to Lend in Synthetic Assets

Tags: finance

You are given:

(i) The price of a stock is 43.00$

(ii) The continuously compounded risk-free interest rate is 5%

(iii) The stock pays a dividend of 1 three months from now

(iv) A 3-month European call option on the stock with strike 44 costs 1.90

You wish to create this stock synthetically, using a combination of 44-Strike Options expiring in 3 months and lending: Determine the amount of money you should lend.

So far I understand that using the Put-Call parity:

$C-P=S_0-PV(Dividend)-Ke^{-rt}$

and for a synthetic stock:
$S_0=C-P+PV(Dividend)+Ke^{-rt}$

Hence:

$S=1.90-P+44e^{-0.0125}+e^{-0.0125}$

When I check the solution, it says that the amount to lend is

$45e^{-0.0125}=44.4410$

Where did this answer come from? How can I approach this type of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Put-Call parity
$$
\begin{align*}
C(S, K, T)−P(S, K, T) &=S−PV(Divs)−K \,\mathrm{e}^{−rT}\\
\Longrightarrow\quad S &= C(S, K, T)−P(S, K, T) +\overbrace{K\, \mathrm{e}^{−rT}+PV(Divs)}^{\text{amount to lend}}
\end{align*}
$$
and then
$$
\begin{align*}
C(S, 44, 0.25)−P(S, 44, 0.25) &=S−PV(Divs)−K \,\mathrm{e}^{−0.05(0.25)}\\
\Longrightarrow\quad S &= C(S, 44, 0.25)−P(S, 44, 0.25)+\overbrace{K\, \mathrm{e}^{−0.0125}+PV(Divs)}^{\text{amount to lend}}\\
&=C(S, 44, 0.25)−P(S, 44, 0.25)+44\, \mathrm{e}^{−0.0125}+\mathrm{e}^{−0.0125}\\
&=C(S, 44, 0.25)−P(S, 44, 0.25)+45\, \mathrm{e}^{−0.0125}
\end{align*}
$$
So the amount to lend is $45\, \mathrm{e}^{−0.0125}=44.4410$.